# how to upload file to IPFS using expressjs and nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, ipfs

I am trying to upload file onto IPFS.
My code is as below

```
var express = require('express')
var fs = require('fs')
const { create, globSource } = require('ipfs-http-client')
const ipfs = create()

....

const filesAdded = await ipfs.add(
    { path: fileName, content: file },
    {
      progress: (len) => console.log('Uploading file...' + len),
    },
  )
  console.log(filesAdded)
  const fileHash = filesAdded.cid.toString()
```

This code return hash value.
But i can't see my file(image) on `https://ipfs.io/ipfs/{hash}`